# What happens if I complete the title screen puzzle?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I have beaten Isaac the Cathedral level once, and when I returned to the title screen, there was a rectangle with what appeared to be a piece of a puzzle in it. I infer that I can complete the puzzle by beating Isaac with each character. Is this the way to complete the puzzle, and what happens when I complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guesses are correct. The puzzle is completed by beating the Cathedral six times.

Here it is after my second victory against Isaac:

[image: unlock 2]

Completing the puzzle unlocks the Polaroid trinket, an item that shields Isaac when brought to 1/2 heart, but that also

> unlocks the final level, the Chest, if you beat Isaac while equipping it. This is the only way to access it and get to the TRUE final boss, [???](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/%3F%3F%3F_(boss)). Beating Isaac with it also unlocks Dad's Key.

Comment: I am pretty sure that spoiler is totally incorrect. I have gotten that boss a few times without getting the Polaroid and now bringing  the Polaroid to Isaac lets you access the chest.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The spoiler was correct when it was written due to a bug present in v1.1. It has been fixed since then. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: You dont have to beat [Isaac](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Isaac_%28boss%29) boss in the Cathedral with every character in order to unlock the Polaroid trinket, you just have to beat him six times, with whoever character you want to.

Comment: @brianakias thanks for the correction, I've updated the answer.